# Triggering a child component event when testing parent

Tags: angular, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm trying to trigger an event emitter from a child component within my parent component cypress test. This are the relevant bits from my child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})

export class ToolbarComponent {

  @Output() showSideNav = new EventEmitter();

  openSideNav() {
    this.showSideNav.emit();
  }
```

The relevant html:

```
  <button
      data-cy="menu-button"
      (click)="openSideNav()"
      mat-icon-button
      aria-label="Application menu button">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

This is the html from my parent component:

```
<app-toolbar data-cy="toolbar" [loggedOnUser$]="loggedOnUser$" (showSideNav)="drawer.toggle()"></app-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav data-cy="sidenav-menu" #drawer mode="side">
      <p data-cy="first-menu-item" class="mx-5 mt-3 mb-4">Menu</p>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This is the test I currently have:

```
  describe('sidenav', () => {
        it('should open when drawer is toggled', () => {
            cy.get('[data-cy=toolbar]').trigger('showSideNav');
            cy.get('[data-cy=first-menu-item]').should('be.visible');
        });
    });
```

This is the output I'm getting from the failed cypress test:

[image]

Not really sure how to approach this as I'm fairly new to Cypress. Can anyone give any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: `cy.get('[data-cy=toolbar]').trigger('showSideNav', {force:true});` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, even with `force:true` the original issue still persists

Comment: The cypress code and the code shown in the screenshot doesn't match. Aren't they same?